# Linux shell scripting: How to store output from terminal in integers (but only numbers)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io, scripting

I'm new to shell scripting and here is my problem:
I want to store PID's from output of `airmon-ng check` to some variables (for ex: $1, $2, $3) so that I can execute `kill $1 $2 $3`.
here is sample output of `airmon-ng check`:

```
Found 3 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

  PID Name
  707 NetworkManager
  786 wpa_supplicant
  820 dhclient
```

I want to grab numbers **707**, **786**, **820**.
I tried using `set 'airmon-ng check'` and then using for loop:

```
set `airmon-ng check`
n=$#
for (( i=0; i<=n; i++ ))
do
        echo $i
done
```

it outputs 1,2,3,...36
not words or numbers so I couldn't figure out how I should do it.

Comment: I think There will be a better way to do this but I can't figure it out. So any ways are accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
airmon-ng check | egrep -o '\b[0-9]+\b' | xargs kill
```

`egrep` is grep with extended regular expressions (like `grep -E`), `-o` says to extract only the matching parts, `\b` matches word boundaries so you don't get any numbers accidentally occuring in process names or something, `[0-9]+` matches one or more decimal digit, `xargs kill` passes all the matches as arguments to the `kill` command.

Note that parsing output intended to be read by humans might not always be a good idea. Also, just killing all those processes doesn't sound too smart either, but proper usage of airocrack is beyond this question.

Comment: Not sure if this captures just the pids. You need a tighter check

Comment: Yeah, but the approach isn't stable anyway. It's just one more issue on top of thousands of other ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can get list of the PIDs separated by spaces e.g. like this (everything from the 1st column after "PID"):

```
l=`airmon-ng check | awk 'BEGIN { p=0 } { if (p) { print $1" "; } if ($1=="PID") { p=1 } }' | tr '\n' ' '`
```

Comment: Didn't even thought of it, Awesome.
Real big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` for this and store the output in an array

```
pids=( $(airmon-ng check | awk '/^[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]+/{print $1}') )
#'pids' is an array
kill "${pids[@]}" #killing all the processes thus found.
```

Comment: real nice approach thanks. Unfortunately my rating is so low that I Can't Upvote the answer :)

Comment: @Ika : Not a problem pal, you enjoy the life :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use grep?

```
myvar=$(airmon-ng check | grep '[0-9]\{3,6\}')
```

This assumes a PID of 3 to 6 digits, and will grab anything from the airmon-ng output of a similar length. So this may not work as well if the output includes other strings with digits of a similar length.

Comment: Not sure if this will output just the pids. What if the o/p contains numbers other than pids?

Comment: @sjsam Unfortunately I am not as well-versed in regexp as I'd like to be and put something together that would fit the typical PID format.

Comment: Hmm.. From the output we may assume that the pids appear at the beginning, you just need a bit of googling to do the rest.